# Global Js not working in Dynamicaly created Component Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am creating a chat app using angular 2 .
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3

My chat boxes are loading dynamically .

I am using material design lite for design.
I have included material design lite js file in index.html which should work globally in all components.

But the material design lite js is only workng in app.component
not in the dynamically generated component.

My component hierarchyis:

`-- App Component
       -- Connection Component
           -- ChatRoom Component`

The App Component and Connection Component gets loaded on app start.
The ChatRoom Component loads dynamically on button click.

Comment: why include `.js` file ? why not `.ts` file ?

Comment: i have `<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>` in my index.html , From where can i get ts file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) instead of [material design lite](https://getmdl.io/index.html). Angular material gives all the [components](https://material.angular.io/components) which are available in other material design libraries but can be integrated with Angular with ease.